What precisely is the nature of humility?
What exactly is the nature of humility and where is the line drawn between being humble and having too low self-esteem?

As covered in the chapter on the trait Humility in Mesilat Yisharim and many other sources, humility is recognising that one's talents are gifts from Hashem, and not personally created:

ואמנם מי שהוא בעל שכל ישר, אפלו אם זכה להיות חכם גדול ומפלג באמת,
כשיסתכל ויתבונן יראה שאין מקום לגאוה והתנשאות, כי הנה מי שהוא בעל שכל
שידע יותר מהאחרים, אינו עושה אלא שבחק טבעו לעשות, כעוף שמגביה לעוף לפי
שטבעו בכך, השור מושך בכחו לפי שחקו הוא. כן מי שהוא חכם הוא לפי שטבעו
מביאו לזה, ואלו אותו שעכשו אינו חכם כמוהו היה לו שכל טבעי כמוהו היה
מתחכם כמו שנתחכם הוא, אם כן אין כאן להתנשא ולהתגאות,
One who possesses a straight intellect, even if he has merited to
become a great sage and truly distinguished, when he looks and
contemplates, will see that there is no room for haughtiness and
pride. For behold, he who possesses high intelligence, who knows more
than others, merely does what it is his nature to do. He is like a
bird which flies upwards because of its nature, or an ox which pulls
with its might because of its nature. So too for he who is wise. This
is because his nature brings him to this. But for another person who
is currently not as wise as him, if he had possessed natural
intelligence like him, would also have become just as wise. Hence,
there is no room to elevate and pride oneself in this.

and therefore not assuming one is great because of them. One feels that if these gifts were given to someone else, they would do better with them.
This does not lead to low self esteem. One is honest about one's talents and feels grateful for them, and does one's best to utilise them to make the world better and serve Hashem, without any self-aggrandizing thoughts.

הנה כלל הענוה היות האדם בלתי מחשיב עצמו משום טעם שיהיה.
The general matter of Humility is for a person not to attribute
importance to himself for any reason whatsoever.

Humility is in thought and deed. We are not arrogant, but humble, about our lacks, as well as what good we have done. This is all covered in Mesilat Yisharim.
